# NoReverseMatch when trying to access view from template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, python-3.4, django-urls

I am getting a NoReverseMatch error for the following:

```
<a href ="{% url 'mainapp:secondaryapp:generateCSV' file_ids=fileids %}">Hello</a>
```

Where I passed a string `fileids` from my view to my template when rendering.

> Reverse for 'generateCSV' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>
> '{'file_ids': '11111111_22222222'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>
> ['mainapp/secondaryapp/generateCSV/(?P[\d{8,20}]+\_*)/$']

My `mainapp/urls.py` is:

```
  from django.conf.urls import url, include  
  from mainapp import views 
  urlpatterns = [
                 ...
                 url(r'^secondaryapp/', include('secondaryapp.urls', namespace="secondaryapp")),
                ]
```

and `secondaryapp/urls.py` is:

```
  from django.conf.urls import url          
  from search import views                                                        
  urlpatterns = [                                                                 
                   url(r'^$', views.secondaryapp.as_view(), name='secondaryapp'),          
                   url(r'^generateCSV/(?P<file_ids>[\d{8,20}]+\_*)/$', views.generateCSV, name='generateCSV'),                     

                ]
```

`generateCSV` is a functional view, and `secondaryapp` is the name of the class-based view. I am rendering the template within the class based view, and attempting to call the functional view with the parameter `fileids`.

If I simply hard-code the url as follows:

```
  <a href = "generateCSV/{{fileids}}/">
```

Everything works as expected.

Thanks very much for your time reading and for any help you can give me!

Comment: That was actually how I originally was trying to do the reverse; however, it gave me a NoReverseMatch where it had 0 pattern(s) tried: []. I [looked it  up](https://www.webforefront.com/django/namedjangourls.html) and found that you have to give the correct namespaces explicitly for the right urlpattern to be referenced. The problem is with the argument somehow not being appended to the url and then matched against the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine pointed out that my regex was wrong; if you use the following in `secondaryapp/urls.py`

```
  url(r'^generateCSV/(?P<fileids>(?:\d{8,20}_)*\d{8,20}?)/$', views.generateCSV, name='generateCSV'),
```

with the following in `secondaryapp/templates/secondaryapp/template.html`

```
  <a href = "{% url 'mainapp:secondaryapp:generateCSV' fileids %}">
```

then things work as expected.

Apparently, it was the square brackets that did me in when attempting to use them for grouping with special characters; according to him, they turn what are normally operators into regular characters, and potentially caused me to accept commas and braces as well.

According to [this](https://qualysguard.qualys.com/qwebhelp/fo_portal/module_pc/policies/regular_expression_symbols.htm):

> "Within square brackets, most characters are interpreted literally."